# Onclick auto popup code

Tags: javascript, popup, onload

I want to know that how can i create a JavaScript code that must open a new page at click anywhere at website. currently i am using onload script.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_on_entrance(url,name)
{
   window.open('http://realestatepakistan.pk','Real Estate Pakistan')
}
</script>
<body onload="open_on_entrance()"></body
```

but onload is not effective as it opens very low number of pages. A must must open page script needed fro my web http://pkr.com.pk/.

Comment: To clarify you want it to open the page in a new window no matter where the user clicks on the web page?

Comment: Check out my live example and see if that is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

This code will open the popup when you click anywhere on website.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var shouldOpenWindow = true;
function open_on_click(url,name) {
   if (shouldOpenWindow) {
      window.open('http://realestatepakistan.pk','Real Estate Pakistan');
      // if you want that only on first click the popup must be opened, and not on any subsequent clicks, then do this
      shouldOpenWindow = !shouldOpenWindow;

   }
}
</script>
<body onclick="open_on_click()"></body>
```

Comment: thank you so much Ammar i am using it and will see the statistics of 24 hours! although its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in a script tag right before your closing `</body>` tag that way it will load after the dom has loaded. You will notice that I removed your parameters from your function because you were not using them inside of your script. Make sure you change the values of `window.open` to the values you need for your script.

**JavaScript:**([live example](http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/grPYjX))

```
function open_on_entrance() {    

  window.open('http://bytewarestudios.com','Welcome to Byteware Studios');

}

document.addEventListener("click", function() {
  open_on_entrance();
});
```

If you decide to the add the parameters back in make sure you supply them to your function when you call it.

**Example Using Parameters:**

```
function open_on_entrance(url,name) {    

     window.open(url,name);

}

document.addEventListener("click", function() {

      var url = 'http://bytewarestudios.com';

      var name = 'Welcome to Byteware Studios';

      open_on_entrance(url,name);
});
```

Comment: Larry i will definitely consider this code in my other project.!

Comment: @Khan not a problem, I hope you find it useful.